# Regex to encode an URL with special characters

Tags: regex

I need to encode a string that contains special characters such as whitespaces, ' and ".

I don't know how to create a regex.

I've tried many solutions but none of them seem to work.

My final objective is to have a string such as "black cat" encoded like this "black%20cat".

EDIT:
Guys I'm working with a specific software called "Axway policy studio" and it has a component where you put in a regex and a string, in the end you get boolean output such as true or false.

Comment: There's a ready-made function in nearly every language/platform for this - surely you don't have to create a regex for this yourself.

Comment: *"Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."* - [regex tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds more like your trying to encode things to make them more appropriate for a URL, which does not require you to write your own regex in most platforms.

For instance, in Python, there's the function `urllib.parse.urlencode` which would do this. In Javascript, there's `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`.

**TL;DR** Look up *urlencode in*  and you'll probably find what you need. Don't bother writing regexes for it unless you really need to.

**P.S.** Most of the urlencoding is just replacing characters with `%` followed by their ascii hex value (`' '` => `%20`, `'!'` => `%21`, ...)